# Google authentication problem (Flutter and Firebase)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am flutter-newbie and I have one problem: I want to add Google authentication to my flutter app with firebase. This is my code for login screen:

```
import 'package:PixiCall/resources/firebase_repository.dart';
import 'package:PixiCall/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  FirebaseRepository _repository = FirebaseRepository();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: loginButton(),
    );
  }

  Widget loginButton() {
    return FlatButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(35),
      child: Text(
        'Login',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 25,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
          letterSpacing: 1.2,
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: () => performLogin,
    );
  }

  void performLogin() {
    _repository.signIn().then((User user) {
      if (user != null) {
        authenticateUser(user);
      } else {
        print('There was an error');
      }
    });
  }

  void authenticateUser(User user, BuildContext context) {
    _repository.authenticateUser(user).then((isNewUser) {
      if (isNewUser) {
        _repository.addDataToDb(user).then((value) {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
            return HomeScreen();
          }));
        });
      } else {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          return HomeScreen();
        }));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I have this error here:
lib/screens/login_screen.dart:39:25: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.

```
    authenticateUser(user);
```

What is the other parameter which I have to add?

Also I think that I have one more mistake in other file. This is the code from other file:

```
import 'package:PixiCall/models/user.dart';
import 'package:PixiCall/utils/utilities.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class FirebaseMethods {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  static final FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  //user class
  User1 user = User1();

  Future<User> getCurrentUser() async {
    User currentUser;
    currentUser = await _auth.currentUser;
    return currentUser;
  }

  Future<User> signIn() async {
    GoogleSignInAccount _signInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication _signInAuthentication =
        await _signInAccount.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: _signInAuthentication.accessToken,
      idToken: _signInAuthentication.idToken,
    );

    User user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    return user;
  }

  Future<bool> authenicateUser(User user) async {
    QuerySnapshot result = await firestore
        .collection('users')
        .where('email', isEqualTo: user.email)
        .get();

    final List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = result.docs;

    //if user is registered then length of list > 0 or else less than 0
    return docs.length == 0 ? true : false;
  }

  Future<void> addDataToDb(User currentUser) async {
    String username = Utils.getUsername(currentUser.email);

    user = User1(
        uid: currentUser.uid,
        email: currentUser.email,
        name: currentUser.displayName,
        profilePhoto: currentUser.photoURL,
        username: username);

    firestore.collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).set(user.toMap(user));
  }
}
```

This is the mistake in console:
lib/resources/firebase_methods.dart:32:17: Error: A value of type 'UserCredential' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'User'.

Sorry if I confused you, as I said, I am newbie. If you want any other informations please ask here.

Answer (score 0):

For the first mistake , you defined a function `void authenticateUser(User user, BuildContext context)` so when you use it, it expects 2 arguments a User type object and a BuildContext object
Then you are calling this function in

```html
void performLogin() {
    _repository.signIn().then((User user) {
      if (user != null) {
        authenticateUser(user);
      } else {
        print('There was an error');
      }
    });
  }
```

You are passing only the User object, missing the BuildContext

Comment: Thank you! I fixed the first mistake. For the second mistake, I tried to change User to User Credential, like this:
UserCredential user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    return user;
Now I got this error: A value of type 'UserCredential' can't be returned from method 'signIn' because it has a return type of 'Future<User>'.
I am not sure what is this...

Answer (score 0):

For GoogleSingIn this was my solution:

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;   
 final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  //create user object based on FB json
  User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null
        ? User(uid: user.uid, emailVerified: user.isEmailVerified)
        : null;
  }



  //auth change user stream
  Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }
```

---

```
Future<User> singInUsingGoogle() async {
int age;
String email;
String name;
String lastname;
final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
                          idToken: googleAuth.idToken, accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken);


final result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

FirebaseUser user = result.user;

print(result.user.providerData);

await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).createUserData(
//user info
)
```

Comment: FirebaseUser is deprecated.